# Shared and unique lines from large files. Fastest method?

Tags: windows, list, powershell, text

This code returns unique and shared lines between two files. Unfortunately, it runs forever if the files have 1 million lines. Is there a faster way to do this (e.g., [-eq, -match, wildcard, Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)) or containment operators are the optimal approach?

```
$afile = Get-Content (Read-Host "Enter 'A' file")
$bfile = Get-Content (Read-Host "Enter 'B' file")

$afile |
  ? { $bfile -notcontains $_ } |
  Set-Content lines_ONLY_in_A.txt

$bfile |
  ? { $afile -notcontains $_ } |
  Set-Content lines_ONLY_in_B.txt

$afile |
  ? { $bfile -contains $_ } |
  Set-Content lines_in_BOTH_A_and_B.txt
```

Comment: Does this have something to do with your other question? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126315/)

Comment: This is a stand alone question. The one you are pointing uses `-match`.

Comment: If the files are sorted (or if you keep them sorted), you might want do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: Love the binary search strategy, I am looking into powershell or python solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my answer to a previous question of yours, `-contains` is a slow operation, particularly with large arrays.

For exact matches you could use `Compare-Object` and discriminate the output by side indicator:

```
Compare-Object $afile $bfile -IncludeEqual | ForEach-Object {
    switch ($_.SideIndicator) {
        '<=' { $_.InputObject | Add-Content 'lines_ONLY_in_A.txt' }
        '=>' { $_.InputObject | Add-Content 'lines_ONLY_in_B.txt' }
        '==' { $_.InputObject | Add-Content 'lines_in_BOTH_A_and_B.txt' }
    }
}
```

If that's still too slow try reading each file into a hashtable:

```
$afile = Get-Content (Read-Host "Enter 'A' file")
$ahash = @{}
$afile | ForEach-Object {
    $ahash[$_] = $true
}
```

and process the files like this:

```
$afile | Where-Object {
    -not $bhash.ContainsKey($_)
} | Set-Content 'lines_ONLY_in_A.txt'
```

If that still doesn't help you need to identify the bottleneck (reading the files, comparing the data, doing multiple comparisons, ...) and proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$All=@()
$All+= Get-Content "c:\temp\a.txt" | %{[pscustomobject]@{Row=$_;File="A"}}
$All+= Get-Content "c:\temp\b.txt" | %{[pscustomobject]@{Row=$_;File="B"}}
$All | group row | %{

$InA=$_.Group.File.Contains("A")
$InB=$_.Group.File.Contains("B")

if ($InA -and $InB)
{
    $_.Group.Row | select -unique | Out-File c:\temp\lines_in_A_And_B.txt -Append
}
elseif ($InA)
{
   $_.Group.Row | select -unique | Out-File c:\temp\lines_Only_A.txt  -Append
}
else
{
   $_.Group.Row | select -unique | Out-File c:\temp\lines_Only_B.txt -Append
}


}
```

Comment: Thank you to both, @ansgar-wiechers. I am testing these suggestions and will report back.

Answer (score 0):

Considering my suggestion to do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), I have created a reusable `Search-SortedArray` function for this:

### Description

The `Search-SortedArray` (alias `Search`) (binary) searches a string in a sorted array. If the string is found, the index of the found string in the array is returned. Otherwise, if the string is not found, a `$Null` is returned.

```
Function Search-SortedArray ([String[]]$SortedArray, [String]$Find, [Switch]$CaseSensitive) {
    $l = 0; $r = $SortedArray.Count - 1
    While ($l -le $r) {
        $m = [int](($l + $r) / 2)
        Switch ([String]::Compare($find, $SortedArray[$m], !$CaseSensitive)) {
            -1  {$r = $m - 1}
            1   {$l = $m + 1}
            Default {Return $m}
        }
    }
}; Set-Alias Search Search-SortedArray


$afile |
    ? {(Search $bfile $_) -eq $Null} |
    Set-Content lines_ONLY_in_A.txt

$bfile |
    ? {(Search $afile $_) -eq $Null} |
    Set-Content lines_ONLY_in_B.txt

$afile |
    ? {(Search $bfile $_) -ne $Null} |
    Set-Content lines_in_BOTH_A_and_B.txt
```

*Note 1*: Due to the overhead, a binary search will only give advantage with (very) large arrays.

*Note 2*: The array has to be sorted otherwise the result will be unpredictable.

*Nate 3*: The search doesn't account for duplicates. In case of duplicate values, just one index will be returned (which isn't a concern for this specific question)

---

Added 2017-11-07 based on the comment from @Ansgar Wiechers:

> Quick benchmark with 2 files with a couple thousand lines each (including duplicate lines): binary search: 2400ms; compare-object: 1850ms; hashtable lookup: 250ms

The idea is that the [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) will take its advantage on the long run: the larger the arrays the more it will proportional gain performance.

Taken `$afile |? { $bfile -notcontains $_ }` as an example, the performance measurements in the comment and that “a couple thousand lines” is 3000 lines:

- For a standard search, you will need an average of 1500 iterations in the `$bfile`:<sup>*1</sup>

  ```
  (3000 + 1) / 2 = 3001 / 2 = 1500
  ```
- For a binary search, you will need an average of 6.27 iterations in the `$bfile`:

  ```
  (log2 3000 + 1) / 2 = (11.55 + 1) / 2 = 6.27
  ```

In both situations you do this 3000 times (for each item in `$afile`)
This means that each single iteration takes:

- For a standard search: `250ms / 1500 / 3000 = 56 nanoseconds`
- For a binary search: `2400ms / 6.27  / 3000 = 127482 nanoseconds`

The breakeven point will at about:

```
56 * ((x + 1) / 2 * 3000) = 127482 * ((log2 x + 1) / 2 * 3000)
```

Which is (according my calculations) at about **40000** entries.

<sub>*1 presuming that a hashtable lookup doesn’t do a binary search itself as it is unaware that the array is sorted</sub>

---

Added 2017-11-07

**Conclusion** from the comments: Hash tables appear to have a similar [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) algorithms that can't be outperformed with low-level programming commands.

Comment: Thank you. It will be some time before I report back, as I am testing these options with large files.

Comment: Quick benchmark with 2 files with a couple thousand lines each (including duplicate lines): binary search: 2400ms; compare-object: 1850ms; hashtable lookup: 250ms.

Comment: Thank you, very useful information. With my limited measurements, the hashtable seems to be the fastest. Still testing.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers, thank you for your benchmark, taken that “a couple thousand lines” is 3000 lines I have calculated and explained where and how a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) should technically gain it's advantage above a standard search at the long run in my answer.

Comment: @iRon The 250ms mark is from the hashtable approach. Hashtables do index lookups, not linear searches (that's what the `-contains` operator does, which makes it so slow), hence you'll never reach a break even. On the contrary, the difference will grow even more with increasing array size. Index lookups will always be significantly faster than a binary search.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers, despite my calculation and the theoretical advantage of a binary search, I just came to the same conclusion: the larger the arrays the longer the binary search will take. I presume it is the overhead from the low-level PowerShell instructions (which are performed for each item in `$afile`) vs. the high-level algorithm behind `.ContainsKey($_)`.

Comment: Based on some further tests, I think that hashtables keys are indexed (similar to if they were sorted). 10x a `ContainsKey` in a hashtable with the size of 3000 items takes 8.3ms as for 30000 items it takes only 0.1ms more (total: 8.4ms) . Apparently, I have under estimated hashtables as nothing more than an a lookup table which is definitely not the case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Answer (score 0):

Full code for the best option (@ansgar-wiechers). A unique, B unique, and A,B shared lines:

```
$afile = Get-Content (Read-Host "Enter 'A' file")
$ahash = @{}
$afile | ForEach-Object {
    $ahash[$_] = $true
}

$bfile = Get-Content (Read-Host "Enter 'B' file")
$bhash = @{}
$bfile | ForEach-Object {
    $bhash[$_] = $true
}

$afile | Where-Object {
    -not $bhash.ContainsKey($_)
} | Set-Content 'lines_ONLY_in_A.txt'

$bfile | Where-Object {
    -not $ahash.ContainsKey($_)
} | Set-Content 'lines_ONLY_in_B.txt'

$afile | Where-Object {
    $bhash.ContainsKey($_)
} | Set-Content 'lines_in _BOTH_A_and_B.txt'
```